# Remove extra part after clipping in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, clip

Clipping allows me to draw only the part which I want to show. How do I remove the extra part which is not drawn but still takes up space?

[image: screenshot]

---

The code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ClipTut extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipRect(
              clipper: CustomRect(),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(width: 4, color: Colors.black),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                width: 200.0,
                height: 200.0,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(width: 4, color: Colors.black),
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomRect extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  @override
  Rect getClip(Size size) => Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0.0, size.width/2, size.height);

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomRect oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Comment: not sure what you're trying to achieve. Can't your left container be just small without the right border?

Comment: it is a sample for the problem, which is:: I can clip certain parts of the widget for drawing, but how do I make the rest of the undrawn part not take up space. In this example, if I did not clip the blue container it would take up the whole space next to the green container. Now, the blue container is clipped it shows some part of the container but takes up the complete space.

Comment: I think ClipRect only take the space you want to show, not clip the widget to new widget, so the widget after be clipped still there but only show the part you clipped. What do you want to do with that? I will help if I can

Comment: yes exactly, clipping the widget shows some part, but the rest of the part still remains. Is there a way to get rid of the remaining part?

Comment: you could use `Stack` but honestly what is the reason for such strange widget clipping?

Comment: I want to make draggable jigsaw puzzle pieces widgets like https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/167408/isolated/lists/30ecf9486dd4788ff3935957f1118476-detail-puzzle-piece-flat.png. I can cut the image into such shape using `ClipPath` but still the extra piece takes up the space

Comment: you could use `Stack` then (or `Flow` widget)

Comment: but honestly you will get **much, much** better UI/UX if you use a `CustomPaint` widget

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. will look into that.

Answer (score 2):

### My Solution

I had a similar problem recently (I needed to clip the image in half) and found this sample code on the [flutter api site](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRect-class.html) (use the other alignment points to change slicing behaviors) - no extra space left over:

```
ClipRect(
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    heightFactor: 0.5,
    child: Image.network(userAvatarUrl),
  ),
)
```