# How to assign image with grid in flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, gridview, flutter-layout, grid

I have an image of 200*200 px in asset. I want to assign grid to this single image say 5 X 5. Example below.

This is what I am doing now.

```
Stack(
        children: [
          GridView.builder(
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 5,
              mainAxisSpacing: 1,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              );
            },
          ),
          Image.asset("assets/chair.png"),
        ],
      )
```

But the output is not fixed, grid varies from screen to screen.
Now the question is how can I assign single image with fixed grid,say 5*5 so that I can get same grid position in all screen size?.

**Remember: I am not trying to modify image here**

Right now all the resource are related to how to divide image into grid view.

**Expected Output in all screen**
[image]

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/58369266/16974425

Comment: This require change in image, which require isolate to perform task. Just wanted to assign fixed grid to image irrespective of device screen.

Comment: you mean you want to use grid in image bg right if you just want to show it in app you can use stack and place image on grid

Comment: That is what I did but it does't fulfil my requirement. You can see in image I have 5X4 grid. Now if I change the screen size grid count also change.